# generate and save sequential number on POST

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

I have a form that uses **Post** to send info to a PHP page.

**The PHP page;**

- Takes the form info.
- Rearranges it.
- Formats it.
- Then turns it into a code string that's ultimately sent to another
  page and performs some tasks using that info.

**Form Code:**

```
<form method="post" action="_php/buildMyPNR.php" name="GuestInfo" 
      onSubmit="return validateFormMethod1();">

<input type="text" name="AccountNumber" id="BID" 
       onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" size ="16"/>

<input type="hidden" name="requestID" id="RID" value="" />

..... bunch of other fields

<input type="submit" name="loadURL" id="submit" value="Submit" 
       onsubmit="return ValidateFields();" />

</form>
```

**What I need to do is;**

- Generate a sequential number each time the page is used.
- Pass that number with the post request (Sort of like a serial number
  for the request), to another form say **_php/buildMyPNR.php**.
- When **_php/buildMyPNR.php** loads, save the values of
  **AccountNumber** and **requestID** to a database or similar.
- Ultimately it would move on to **_php/usageSummary.php**, where the user can click
  a button to return a list of **AccountNumbers** paired with the
  **requestID** that was generated for the request.
- Possibly download the list in an excel spreadsheet format, but it is
  not absolutely necessary.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Mainly I need help with generating the **requestID**. I need them to be sequential so I assume that I would need to start with a number in my database like 00001, query that number from my form, add 1 to the returned value, then save the new value along with the **AccountNumber** when submit is pressed.

I have no experience with databases and any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally we'd see some schema and examples of code you've already tried...

However, you can use an Auto Increment field in your Database Table, which will accomplish the ID incrementing for you.

[image]

If you're using mysqli for your mysql database interaction (as you perhaps should be), then you can then retrieve this autonumber using;

```
$PassedRequestID = $mysqli->insert_id
```

Then pass this to your next page.

You will then need to query your database with something like (psuedo code);

```
SELECT Accounts.*, Requests.*
INNER JOIN Requests ON Requests.AccountID = Accounts.AccountID
WHERE Requests.RequestID = $PassedRequestID
```

For exporting to Excel, if you search for *PHP export CSV* using Google, there'll be plenty of examples there to choose from. However, as an example;

http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/creating-downloadable-csv-files/

Comment: Thank you very much. I wasnt sure of the terminology used to refer to what I needed (ended up with a lot of unrelated and over complicated stuff in google). Your explanation definitely puts me on track to get this done. Thank you again!!